# What user should I use for wp-cli on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: wp-cli, linux

I have set-up my first VPS (Ubuntu). Apache 2 and php were pre-installed, I was able to install wp-cli, but it is kinda useless for me know. I am getting user permissions error. For example when I run

```
wp core download
```

I am getting an error

```
Error: /var/www/example.com/public_html/ is not writable by current user
```

I am using user which is member of `root` group and I have also tried to add user into a `www-data` group. The folder `public_html` is own by `www-data:www-data` (default Apache settings).

I know that this might be more Ubuntu than Wordpress issue, but I though this is still better place to ask the question than AskUbuntu.com. If I am wrong, I don't mind moving this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is very clear. The owner of `public_html` is `www-data`, you don't have any permisson to write to that folder.

You can use whatever user you want as long as that user have permission to read, write and execute your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. But you shouldn't use `root` user.

So, to solve that error, try:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

That's all ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the file owner is allowed to run a shell I find that su-ing to that user works fine. I'm running suPHP so each site has its own user which can login. I don't know if the default Apache user is more restricted.

I wouldn't follow the advice to chown the files as your web server might then choke.